# Finding the root of $8=4t+3\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to find this root?

$8=4t+3\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$

I can't get my brain around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try plotting line $\frac{8- 4*t}{3}$ and the curve $sin(\frac{\pi}{2}*t)$?

Comment: Yeah I mean manually, I know it's t=2 by plotting.

Comment: So you found the root! What's your question exactly?

Comment: That I have to do it by hand :(

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) will approximate the root for you, so if everything goes right, you should find that the approximations approach $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Answered with Newthon-Rhapson method. T=2.

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier, let $t=x+2$ which leads to
$$4 x-3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  }{2}x\right)=0$$ The lhs is an odd function and so, if $x$ is a root, $-x$ ia also a root. So, just focus on the positive root.

Now let $\frac{\pi  }{2}x=y$ to make
$$\frac{8 }{3 \pi }y-\sin (y)=0$$

For a first *approximation*, you could use the magnificent approximation
$$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -y) y}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -y) y}\qquad (0\leq y\leq\pi)$$  proposed, more than $1400$ years ago, by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

This would give the nice result
$$y =\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} \pi \approx 0.970806$$ while the exact solution given by Newton method is $ \approx 0.975334$.

If you still do not want numerical methods, considering that the solution is close to $\frac \pi 3$, let us build the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant.

For $n=0$ (this is the same as the first iteration of Newton method), you would have
$$y_{(0)}=\frac{\left(3 \sqrt{3}-\pi \right) \pi }{16-3 \pi }\approx 0.981654$$
For $n=1$ (this is the same as the first iteration of Halley method), you would have
$$y_{(1)}=\frac{\pi  \left(\pi  \left(96+54 \sqrt{3}+\left(16 \sqrt{3}-45\right) \pi \right)-288
   \sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \pi  \left(192+\left(16 \sqrt{3}-45\right) \pi \right)-1536}\approx 0.975848$$

Now, using Newton method with $y_0=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} \pi$, look how fast is obtained the solution (using a ridiculous number of figures)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{0.97}080551936273328867 \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.9753}6402009863745800 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.97533420}980720014669 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.9753342085296257}4024 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.97533420852962573789}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The graph shows two more roots: $ (1.4,1.6)$ approximately apart from the guessed $x=2$:

[image]

Numerical methods e.g., Newton-Raphson, Regula Falsi are the only recourse for solution of such *transcendental* equations, no analytical solution is possible.